Asymptotic distribution of MLE of $\theta$ for $f(x) = (1-\theta)1_{(-1/2,0)}(x) + (1+\theta)1_{(0,1/2)}(x)$
I am trying to find the asymptotic distribution for $\theta$ given $f(x) = (1-\theta)1_{(-1/2,0)}(x) + (1+\theta)1_{(0,1/2)}(x)$. I've shown that $\hat{\theta} = \frac{T_2 - T_1}{n}$, where $T_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n 1(X_i < 0)$ and $T_2 = \sum_{i=1}^n 1(X_i > 0)$.
Now defining $Y =  T_2 - T_1$ we have that $\bar{Y} = \hat{\theta}$ and by CLT we get that $\sqrt{n}(\bar{Y} - E(Y)) \to N(0, Var(Y))$. I got that $E(Y) = P(X > 0) - P(X < 0) = 1-2P(X < 0) = 1 - 2\cdot \frac{1-\theta}{8} = \frac{3-\theta}{4}$ and $E(Y^2) = P(X > 0) + P(X < 0) = 1$, so $Var(Y) = 1 - \frac{(3-\theta)^2}{16} = \frac{7+6\theta-\theta^2}{16}$. But the exercise asks to check that the asymptotic variance is $\frac{1-\theta^2}{n}$. What am I doing wrong?

For a given $\theta$, I claim that
$$T_1 \mid \theta \sim \operatorname{Binomial}\left(n, p = \frac{1-\theta}{2}\right). \tag{1}$$  This is because $$f_X(x) = (1-\theta)\mathbb 1 (-\tfrac{1}{2} < x < 0) + (1+\theta)\mathbb 1 (0 < x < \tfrac{1}{2}) \tag{2}$$
implies
$$\Pr[X < 0] = \int_{x=-1/2}^0 f_X(x) \, dx = (1-\theta)(0 - (-1/2)) = \frac{1-\theta}{2}. \tag{3}$$
Note $T_2 = n-T_1$, so it follows that the MLE is
$$\hat \theta = \frac{n - 2T_1}{n} = 1 - \frac{2}{n}T_1. \tag{4}$$  So the exact expectation is
$$\operatorname{E}[\hat \theta] = \operatorname{E}\left[1 - \frac{2}{n}T_1\right] = 1 - \frac{2}{n} \operatorname{E}[T_1] = 1 - \frac{2}{n} \cdot \frac{n(1-\theta)}{2} = \theta. \tag{5}$$
Moreover,
$$\operatorname{Var}[\hat \theta] = \operatorname{Var}\left[1 - \frac{2}{n}T_1\right] = \frac{2^2}{n^2} \operatorname{Var}[T_1] = \frac{4}{n^2} n \frac{1-\theta}{2} \frac{1 + \theta}{2} = \frac{1-\theta^2}{n}. \tag{6}$$
There is no need to invoke the CLT here because the statistic $T_1$ obeys a known parametric distribution.

Regarding your work, it is unclear to me how exactly you've defined $Y$.  You say $Y = T_2 - T_1$, but these variables are a function of the sample size $n$.  Yet in the next step you write $\operatorname{E}[Y] = \Pr[X > 0] - \Pr[X < 0]$, which would suggest that you are considering a sample of size $1$.  I'm afraid I don't follow the reasoning.
If $Y$ is defined for a single observation $X$, then $Y = T_2 - T_1$ has mass function
$$\Pr[Y = -1] = \frac{1-\theta}{2}, \quad \Pr[Y = 1] = \frac{1+\theta}{2},$$ hence
$$\operatorname{E}[Y] = -\frac{1-\theta}{2} + \frac{1+\theta}{2} = \theta.$$
If $Y$ is defined for a general sample size $n$, then $Y$ again has discrete support as before, but on the set $\{-n, -n+2, \ldots, n-2, n\}$.  Proceeding further with $Y$ is difficult.

You are absolutely right. I intended to define $Y_1,...Y_n$ where $Y_i = 1$ if $X_i > 0$ and $Y_i = -1$ if $X_i < 0$ but I messed up the notation and calculations. In that case $1/n \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i = \bar{Y} = \hat{\theta}$. Since $E(Y_i) = \theta$ and $E(Y_i^2) = 1$ we get that $Var(Y_i) = 1-\theta^2$ and from there we can find the asymptotic distribution of $\hat{\theta}$ using CLT.
